# Is it cheaper to buy fixed amounts or amounts with fixed price of a fluctuating product?

Tags: distributions

Say the price of something fluctuates with time. From a statistical point of view, is it cheaper (in total cost after a long amount of time) to buy it in large constant amounts of variable quantities of the same price?

I tried modelling this as the following:
Spending a certain amount of money means buying in more increments, which is more sensitive to fluctuations (which can be thought of as random noise) -- this seems similar to a sine wave on a price against time plot. While buying in large amounts, may on average be modelled as a straight horizontal line on the same plot. Integrating the area under those curves on large amounts of time should give us the same answer.

Is there anything else to think about that I'm missing, without going into non-statistical arguments?

Comment: This question isn't very well defined: exactly how is the price fluctuating?  How does one choose when to purchase?  What does "cheaper" mean: smaller in terms of the expected cost, perhaps, or something else? These details matter!  Please elaborate.

Comment: I agree with Bill Huber.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take the liberty of answering the question under some added structure:

1. Your objective is to buy a fixed quantity $Q$ at minimum expected total cost $C_t := q_tp_t + \mathbb{E}_t[q_{t+1}p_{t+1} + q_{t+2}p_{t+2} + \ldots + q_{t+T}p_{t+T}]$ where the subscripts refer to different periods in discrete time, $p_t$ is the current price and the sequence of $\{q_i\}_{i=t}^{t+T}$ must sum to $Q$ and be chosen now. $\mathbb{E}_t$ is the expected value conditional on current information and $t+T$ some terminal period.
2. The expected price tomorrow is the value of the price today: $\mathbb{E}_tp_{t+1} = p_t$. In many contexts, this is a reasonable assumption.

You can check that under these assumptions, $C_t$ takes the same value, $Q p_t$, no matter how you choose the $q_i$. So it does not matter. If you expected the price to say decrease, it would of course make sense to postpone the purchase. As @whuber points out, in order to make the question interesting, you need to think about "non-statistical" arguments from economics or finance: do you care about risk? Is there discounting or some benefit from having the good sooner or later?